# How can I point multiple domains to one server?

Tags: dns, vps

I have a VPS that's barely being used. I would love to point several domains I have (through a registrar somewhere else) to different folders of this VPS. Is there any way to do this?

```
For example:

helloomgwtf.com -> 111.111.111.111/hello
hitherehowareyou.com -> 111.111.111.111/hithere
thirdrandomdomain.com -> 111.111.111.111/random
```

I'm entirely new to setting stuff up, so detailed explanations would *really* be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Virtual Hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName helloomgwtf.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/hello
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hitherehowareyou.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/hithere
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName thirdrandomdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/random
</VirtualHost>
```

Rackspace has pretty good info on this [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-serve-multiple-domains-using-virtual-hosts).